# NiFi EvaluateXPath Processor doesn't return all results

Tags: xml, xpath, apache-nifi

I'm trying to extract a list of IDs from an example XML, and preferably write them into a flowfile attribute.

XML:

```
<Data>
  <Buckets>
    <Data_Item>
      <Data_Info ID="1234">
        <Value>123</Value>
      </Data_Info>
    </Data_Item>
    <Data_Item>
      <Data_Info ID="5678">
        <Value>456</Value>
      </Data_Info>
    </Data_Item>
    <Data_Item>
      <Data_Info ID="9999">
        <Value>789</Value>
      </Data_Info>
    </Data_Item>
  </Buckets>
</Data>
```

XPath:
`/Data/Buckets/Data_Item/Data_Info/@ID`

I tested the XPath with an online editor and it returned all 3 IDs, but when I enter it into the NiFi EvaluateXPath processor it either throws an error or only returns the first ID.

The error happens if I use `nodeset` or `auto-detect` for the return type.
Error Message: `XPath evaluation on ... produced unexpected results [3]`

If I use `string` as the return type I only get the first ID (1234) as a return value.

The same problems occur if I change the destination from `flowfile-attribute` to `flowfile-content`.

How can I extract a list of IDs from the XML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a this XPath Expression (using [string-join](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/xquery/xquery_string_join.htm)):

```xml
string-join(/Data/Buckets/Data_Item/Data_Info/@ID, ',')
```

**input**

```xml
<Data>
  <Buckets>
    <Data_Item>
      <Data_Info ID="1234">
        <Value>123</Value>
      </Data_Info>
    </Data_Item>
    <Data_Item>
      <Data_Info ID="5678">
        <Value>456</Value>
      </Data_Info>
    </Data_Item>
    <Data_Item>
      <Data_Info ID="9999">
        <Value>789</Value>
      </Data_Info>
    </Data_Item>
  </Buckets>
</Data>
```

**output**

```
1234,5678,9999
```